# chown in docker not changing user to root

Tags: macos, docker, centos6.5

I am fairly new to Docker and have been setting up a Dockerfile and compose file to start up a server for testing.

When running a centos:6.6 image with a volume mapped to my user directory in OSX and installing httpd, my user for var/www/html is 1000:ftp instead of root:root.

I need to change a folder to user apache:apache in order to be able to upload files to it and cannot get chown or chmod to make any changes in any folder under var/www/html.
I know this has to do with me mapping my volume to a location on my OS drive.

So, my question is..

Is there anyway to set it up so that I can change ownership of var/www/html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues [587](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/587) or [581](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/581) show that you can not change the ownership of a host mounted directory.

Change instead your Apache start script in order to start it with the right id (1000) instead of apache:apache.
See "[apache/start_safe_perms](https://github.com/kojiromike/docker-magento/blob/master/apache/start_safe_perms)" from Michael A. Smith

Mainly:

```
read owner group owner_id group_id < <(stat -c '%U %G %u %g' .)
adduser --system --uid=$(stat -c %u .) "$owner"
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is exactly what I needed.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The newly released Docker for Mac [has a different behavior](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#/ownership) regarding ownership:

> Initially, any containerized process that requests ownership metadata of an object is told that its uid and gid own the object. When any containerized process changes the ownership of a shared file system object, e.g. with chown, the new ownership information is persisted in the com.docker.owner extended attribute of the object. [...]

Michael's `start_safe_perms` script can be adapted like the following to work consistently across platforms:

```
if [[ -n $(mount -t fuse.osxfs) ]]; then
    chown -R www-data:www-data . 2> /dev/null
    # ...
else
    read owner group owner_id group_id < <(stat -c '%U %G %u %g' .)
    adduser --system --uid=$(stat -c %u .) "$owner"
    # ...
fi
```

It basically detects if the mounted volume if of the type `fuse.osxfs`.

You can checkout [API Platform](https://api-platform.com)'s `start_safe_perms` script for a fully working example: https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/blob/master/docker/apache/start_safe_perms